# How to block own rpcap traffic where tshark is running?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

Platform :- Fedora 13 32-bit machine

RemoteMachine$ ./rpcapd -n

ClientMachine$ tshark -w "filename" -i "any interface name"

As soon as capture starts without any capture filter, thousands of packets get captured. Rpcapd binds to 2002 port by default and while establishing the connection it sends a randomly chosen port number to the client for further communication. Both client and server machines exchange tcp packets through randomly chosen ports. So, I cannot even specify the capture filter to block this rpcap related tcp traffic.

Wireshark & tshark for Windows have an option "Do not capture own Rpcap Traffic" in Remote Settings in Edit Interface Dialog box. But there is no such option in tshark for linux.

It will be also better if anyone can tell me how wireshark blocks rpcap traffic....

Comment: Curious.  Does `dumpcap` show the same symptoms?

Comment: Have you tried a ssh tunnel rather than rpcapd?

Comment: Yes, Dumpcap also behaves in similar manner. Moreover when we enter tshark in command prompt, it forks a child and exec dumpcap with the specified flags. I haven't used SSH tunnel yet. Can you tell me how to use it?

Comment: See [Wireshark: Remote Capture](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes#Remote_Capture) or [How To Monitor Packets From A Remote Interface In Real Time](http://blog.notreally.org/2007/01/24/how-to-monitor-packets-from-a-remote-interface/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a display filter that blocks the RPCAP **protocol**, not the port nor IP address.

I have no data to try, but how does this work?

```
$ tshark -R 'not rpcap' and_then_the_rest_of_your_command
```

Comment: Can you plz tell me how to block RPCAP protocol ???

Comment: It's working fine to block RPCAP but RPCAP is present in those packets only which are used for initiating and closing the process. All other communication takes place over simple TCP Protocol.